# How do I execute SQL queries in parallel from Python and get the data into a separate pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, asynchronous, python-multiprocessing

I have 20 slow running SQL queries against 20 different tables a SQL Server database.

The code looks something like:

```
df01 = pd.read_sql(q01, con=cnxn)
df02 = pd.read_sql(q02, con=cnxn)
...
df20 = pd.read_sql(q20, con=cnxn)
```

Where there is very little overlap between the data being fetched.

I'm looking for a good way to run these queries simultaneously... right now my application hangs for ~10min while it fetches `df1` to `df20`.

I'm not sure whether async/multithreading/multiprocessing is most appropriate. Some info:

- The Python application is essentially idle while the data is being fetched (CPU ussage ~1%)
- The the network is also not saturated (the data returned into each `df` is only a few thousand rows)
- The database is also not saturated because any one query can't leverage all the vCores available.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

PS. I'm using `Python 3.9.7`

Comment: Did you ever get any answer/solution?